# Designing apps on Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design

Since I began designing an app on 1080 x 1920 pixel artboard on Illustrator, how do I give files to developers who are using Xamarin to develop the app on both iOS and Android?

Comment: Ask them what they prefer.

Answer (score 2):

I will also ask them.

Also what you can do is:

- prepare pdf document with all specifications based on your Illustrator design
- use some ready tools for this like: https://specctr.com/cloud/home

I will also consider changing tool for designing UI to some other.
I think that Sketch is much better for this task than Illustrator and Sketch. And have cool plugins to make handover to developer (Zepelin, Avocode) and is not so expensive.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree on Sketch, it's much faster and easier than AI and has a lot of easy plugins for exporting assets. So if you have a mac, I'd def give Sketch a go!

Comment: Will they ever release a PC version?